Old red letter art King James old and new testament with no printing date but Pittsburgh Pa. Is this strange when I see it stop records before 1900
I don't know what to look for as far as this. This is a strange Bible to me and I know nothing about bibles. A I said this is not right and had been altered some how for some reason. Can you give me any insight?

can you clarify what you are wanting? are you trying to identify a bible, do you have images? where did you see it?

send images to social media groups of bibles, or quora, you will get answers about which bible edition is that.

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.
